# why doesn't gcc atomic store with __ATOMIC_RELEASE generate a memory barrier?

Tags: multithreading, gcc, x86-64, atomic

Pikus' "The Art of Writing Efficient Programs" (pp.208) provides a spinlock implementation using C++ atomic variables. I modified this for gcc atomic builtins (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html). I was surprised to see that my unlock function is turned into code without a memory barrier:

```
spin_unlock:    
# spinlock.c:112:   __atomic_store_n(s, 0, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
    mov DWORD PTR [rdi], 0  #,* s,
    ret
```

I thought that memory barriers are only effective if applied pairwise. The lock function (using an atomic exchange with `__ATOMIC_ACQUIRE`) relies on the two implicit memory barriers in `xchg`, but I would have expected that `gcc` (on `x86_64`) generates a `lock mov` or another `xchg` for a store with `__ATOMIC_RELEASE`. Why not?

Comment: Every load and store on x86-64 is already strong enough for acq/rel.  `exchange(ACQUIRE)` doesn't need the extra ordering that comes with the implicit `lock` prefix, it only needs the RMW atomicity.  x86 doesn't have a way to do atomic RMWs weaker than `SEQ_CST`.  You only want `xchg` for a `SEQ_CST` store, otherwise pure-load and pure-store are trivial.